# jquery filereader append all image event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, filereader

I am using this simple script to select and preview multiple image
i want to alert after all image preview complete
but the alert executed before image appended to html element
can any one has an idea how to fix this?

here is a snippet for testing

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
     $("#files").change(function(event) {
   var files = this.files; 
   var i = 0,
     len = files.length;
   (function readFile(n) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     var f = files[n];
     reader.onload = function(e) {
    
    $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
     "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + f.name + "\"/><br/>" +
     "name: "+ f.name +"<br>size: " + f.size
     + "<span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
     "</span>").appendTo("#img");
    $(".remove").click(function(){
     $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
    });
    if (n < len -1) 
                 readFile(++n)
               else 
                 alert("all image displayed");
     };
     reader.readAsDataURL(f); // `f` : current `File` object
     
   }(i)); 
   
   
  });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }


});
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  display: block;
}
.imageThumb {
  max-height: 75px;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.remove {
  display: block;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.remove:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="msg"></p>
   <pre id="debug"></pre>
   <div id="img"></div>
   <div class="field" align="left">
     <h3>Upload your images</h3>
     <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
     <div id="img"></div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your piece of code goes recursively through all the files, creates a `FileReader` for each of them and adds an `onload` callback to each `FileReader`.

This `onload` callback is asynchronous hence the JavaScript engine doesn't wait for any image to be loaded and runs the next statement, `alert("all image displayed");`, after having gone through all the files.

You could add an else statement in `if (n < len -1) readFile(++n)` so the alert would be executed after the last image is loaded

```
if (n < len -1)  {
  readFile(++n);
} else {
  alert("all image displayed");
}
```

Of course, then you should delete the current `alert("all image displayed");`

Comment: though, alert comes before image loaded to element check update snippet

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with loaded but the change that we did fixes the initial issue of "_alert executed before image appended to html element_". Maybe you see the alert before the image is completely  rendered but you can confirm that the images are fully loaded and added into the DOM by adding a `debugger` statement just before the alert. You'll need to wrap the `alert` and the `debugger` in curly brackets